# Python multiple read on stdin cause it to block

Tags: python, stdin

I am a student in programming school and need to complete a project playing with financial stock's data.

I chose to do it in Python as it's the only language I played few days with which is not taught in my school, I must be able to read on the standard input and I am able to it once but not the second time, the program indefinitely wait and I must stop it using ctrl+c raising an KeyboardInterrupt

Here is the code I get :

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                                                                 
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    capital = int(sys.stdin.readline())
    days = int(sys.stdin.readline())
    initial = int(sys.stdin.readline())
    for day in range(days - 1):
    print("wait")
    try:
            value = int(sys.stdin.readline())
    except ValueError:
            break
```

Here is few hint about the input format I am getting.

First I get three numbers in three different lines at once.
Then I get as many input as the second number of the first input so I am looping on it.

As soon as I reach the

```
sys.stdin.readline()
```

in the try/catch the program block and I have actually no idea about why this is happening.

Comment: it is blocking because there are no lines being written ... thats what it does ... it is waiting for a line of input to come to sys.stdin

Comment: your code is doing what it should, you are taking input in the range days

Comment: do you just want to take user input?

Comment: The fact is, this is school project and they are using a program which call mine, so I have no other choice to trust that they are actually sending me something, I have no control over this.

Comment: raw_input will take input from a user but the user still needs to enter it and hit return, what do you want to do exactly? If you don't get an error or the user does not enter days-1 inputs your program is still going to wait in that loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
sys.stdin.readline()
```

use, in Python 2 (which I imagine you're using given the future-import)

```
raw_input()
```

or, in Python 3,

```
input()
```

I believe you may be running into buffering problems given your description of your problems, and the `raw_input` and `input` built-in functions take all the measures needed to avoid buffering problems, so you don't have to dig in at a low level to fix things yourself.

Comment: You indirectly saved my problem
I was using #!/usr/bin/python as a shebang and out school computer integrate python2.7, pŷthon3 and python3.3 so I guess it was using a bunch of different version, I used 3.3 instead and everything is now working with input()

Comment: Actually I tried to specify the 2.7 shebang with raw_input() just as a test and it seems that I am running in the same blocking problem.